# What can I use to chat on Battle.net?

Tags: games, pidgin

In the past there was a Pidgin plugin that allowed users to chat on Battle.net. Does such a thing still exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently [no standalone client for Battle.net](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10890/is-there-a-stand-alone-chat-client-for-battle-net/10891#10891). The only option is to [run the complete StarCraft II game using Wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=20882).

Answer (score 4):

By the developer:

*B-Chat is a Battle.net chat client for Linux. It is currently text based, but plansare in place as of version 0.13 to create a user interface using GTK/Gnome.*

http://sourceforge.net/projects/b-chat/

Comment: This client was last updated 11 years ago and is incompatible with the current version of Battle.net.

Comment: last updated 2009-07-16 ??

Comment: @Alaukik [2000-11-13](http://sourceforge.net/projects/b-chat/files/B-Chat/v0.13/).